# Search UITextView for a specific word in iOS app

Tags: ios

I have added UITextView to an app and the list is kind of long. What is the easy way of searching a word in this list. I can add a button and textfield to enter and search for a word. I was was wondering maybe there is already built feature for UITextView.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

`[TextView.text rangeOfString:];` or something like this.

Comment: What is the searchBar object? Can this be placed just above the uiTextView and use the searchBar to search for a word in TextView? Thanks

Comment: Sure. It's a subclass of UIView. Also your class responsible for search should implement `SearchBarDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Thanks Roman, Can you point me to some article or tutorial that shows searchBar with TextView as I am absolute beginner to iOS. Thanks again

Comment: [link](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html) There no exapmles of searchBar + UITextField, but there's nothing hard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking if there's a search UI built-in for UITextView (like the way the system libraries manage some aspects of the searchDisplayController property on UIViewController).  There is not a built-in feature for this.

One convenient option you might consider is creating a 44 pixel tall view with your search text field and button(s) and then set this view as the "inputAccessoryView" on the UITextView object.  The system will then manage animating its display above the keyboard, and scrolling the UITextView so the user is not typing underneath this view.