# Search mechanisms in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uisearchbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement search function to UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914282/how-to-implement-search-function-to-uitextview)

I have a UIViewContoller which contains huge data in terms of UITextView s. It is difficult for the user to read entire text on the screen. So i am thinking how can i provide search functionality in this scenario ?

I would like to know the possible search mechanisms in iOS. I know one way which is uiSerachBar with uitableview. Is there any other search mechanism available ?

Is it possible to search to mimic MSWord or PDF files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to search all types of documents mimicking the way MSWord or PDF files search. You just have to customize them according to your plan.
Here are a few links please check them out....

[Search UITextView for a specific word in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234857/search-uitextview-for-a-specific-word-in-ios-app)

[How to implement search function to UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914282/how-to-implement-search-function-to-uitextview)

Also , check in [google](http://www.google.com) and this site itself for further queries.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. 2nd Option (How to implement search function to UITextView?) looks good to go for me. But the code i see is in unix project files. I am not able to open it up. Can i get project file for iMac version.